# Translating on the X axis several times and then translating on the Y axis makes the HTML object move back

Tags: javascript, html, css

Before I get into my question, please remember these following things:

1. I have no interest in using a game engine.
2. I am using HTML, CSS and JavaScript to make this game.
3. I am using 3 arrow keys as controls, on the event that someone clicks one, it should move in the direction the arrow is facing.

**Question**

When I click the right arrow key several times, and then press the jump box, the targeted HTML object, `master-cube` moves back to its natural position and then executes the `movejump()` function there, but I want the HTML object to move from its current position.

I understand that `transform` will fire from its natural position, but is there a line of code telling it to run from its current position? That’s what’s desired.

Here is a `repl.it` link: https://repl.it/@ritzcrackerz201/cake

And here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>cake (singleplayer 2d adventure game)</title>
    <style>
        html {
            margin: none;
        }

        body {
            margin: none;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .arrowcontrols {
            float: left;
            margin-right: 5px;
            margin-top: 20%;
            margin-bottom: 80%;
        }

        #master-cube {
            background-image: url("mastercubes/master1.png");
            background-size: 100%;
            height: 40px;
            width: 40px;
            transition: all 0.5s;
      position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    let xarrowmovement = 0;

  function moveright() {
    xarrowmovement += 80;
    document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translateX(${xarrowmovement}%)`;
    console.log("Executing function 'moveright()'. Moving a distance of " + xarrowmovement + "%");
  }

  function moveleft() {
    xarrowmovement += -80; 
    document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translateX(${xarrowmovement}%)`;
    console.log("Executing function 'moveleft()'. Moving a distance of " + xarrowmovement + "%");
  }

  let jumpboxupmovementy = 0;
  function movejump() {
    jumpboxupmovementy += 80;
    document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translateY(${-jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;
    console.log("Executing function 'movejump()'. Moving a distance of " + jumpboxupmovementy + "%");

        setTimeout(function(){ 
      jumpboxupmovementy -= 80;
      document.getElementById("master-cube").style.transform = `translate(${jumpboxupmovementy}%)`;
    }, 500); 
  }
    </script>
    <div id="master-cube"></div>
    <img src="arrows/leftarrow.png" alt="Left Arrow" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="moveleft()" class="arrowcontrols">
    <img src="arrows/middlejumpsquare.png" alt="Jump Square" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="movejump()" class="arrowcontrols">
    <img src="arrows/rightarrow.png" alt="Right Arrow" height="80vh" width="80vw" onclick="moveright()" class="arrowcontrols">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that readers won't consider posting from an iPad to be a sufficient reason why the code is not presented here on Stack Overflow. Someone has kindly fixed that on this occasion. I don't know if it is possible from an iPad, but if not, please use a device that permits you to put the code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is moved back, because you're overwriting the previous translation when you re-assign its value. The easiest way to solve your issue would be to concatenate strings (use `+=` instead of `=`) when assigning to `style.transform`, because transforms may be stacked and you can do stuff like:

```css
#foo {
  transform: translateX(50px)translateY(50px);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">bar</div>
```

That being said, I think a better solution would be to have an object store the x- and y-offsets generated by your inputs and create a translation based on that when required. A basic example follows:

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
const movableObject = document.getElementById('movable-object');
const translation = { x: 0, y: 0 };
const translate = () => {
  movableObject.style.transform = `translate(${translation.x}%,${translation.y}%)`;
};

nav.onclick = ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.classList.contains('nav-arrow')) return;
  switch(target.id) {
    case 'up': 
      translation.y -= 80;
      setTimeout(() => { translation.y = 0; translate(); }, 500);
      break;
    case 'left': 
      translation.x -= 80;
      break;    
    case 'right': 
      translation.x += 80;
      break;
  };
  translate();
};
```

```css
#nav {
  width: 72px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  ". up ."
  "left . right";
}

#up {
  grid-area: up;
}

#left {
  grid-area: left;
}

#right {
  grid-area: right;
}

#movable-object {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
}

.nav-arrow {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <span class="nav-arrow" id="up">&#8593;</span>
  <span class="nav-arrow" id="left">&#8592;</span>
  <span class="nav-arrow" id="right">&#8594;</span>
</div>

<div id="movable-object"></div>
```

Comment: So, how do you suggest to put this into the javascript function?

Comment: @JeffreyLan I've added a basic implementation.

Comment: Would you mind to implement my original movement into the code? If you do, I would be glad to accept this answer.

Comment: @JeffreyLan There you go.